# Reason of high packing density in integrated injection logic family

Tags: integrated-circuit, manufacturing

I have read that in Integrated Circuit manufacturing , resistors are made of either diffusion or metal/poly deposit. In diffused resistors we use the bulk resistance of diffused regions. But why do people say that  the integrated injection    logic family had high packing density due to complete absence of diffused resistors,when it had few diffusion regions ?  I hope my question is    clear.

Comment: It is interesting to see a question about  Isquared L

Comment: actually this question arose because i had taken a course on semiconductor physics and IC manufacturing. Moreover in the coursework of digital integrated circuits we were taught the building blocks of IC. Could you please answer my query ?

Comment: I remember seeing the layout for this where you had the "injection" strip run up the middle between two BJT columns as n+ diffusion in a p-substrate.  I'm not sure that still holds.  I could make injection logic in a standard CMOS process if I have triple wells, but it's going to be larger than MOS just due to the extra area required for the doped regions.  Gates are very small by comparison to junctions.

Comment: I would request you to have a look in the paper "Integrated injection logic:a bipolar LSI technique" by R.A. Pedersen. I know it is very old (1976) ,but I could not understand what he meant to say. You might be able to help me out.

Answer (score 2):

The promise of Integrated Injection Logic (I2L) was a bipolar circuit technology that could achieve LSI density: the speed of bipolar with the density and low power consumption of CMOS. It didn't manage to overtake CMOS, but it's still an interesting technology historically.

The density problem with TTL logic is it uses lots of resistors. On an IC die, a resistor is bulky, consisting of a long, narrow diffusion region snaking around. I2L instead uses a lateral PNP transistor as a current source to inject the base current, avoiding the use of resistors. In addition, the PNP transistor and the NPN transistor for the gate can be combined into a cell without additional wiring, providing a compact layout. (Thus, it has an "integrated injector".)

A detailed explanation of I2L with diagrams is in the paper you mention: "[Integrated injection logic: a bipolar LSI technique](https://www.computer.org/csdl/mags/co/1976/02/01647276.pdf)". You can compare with TTL layout discussed in my article on the TTL [74181 ALU](http://www.righto.com/2017/01/die-photos-and-reverse-engineering.html).

One confusing thing about I2L is it uses multi-collector transistors, while TTL uses multi-emitter transistors. But these are actually the same physical transistor structures, just swapping the collector and emitters for I2L.

Debajyoti, if I'm understanding your original question right, yes I2L does use diffusion for the transistors but it avoids diffusion resistors. It's not diffusion itself that is bad for density, but diffusion resistors.